# Strategy On Building Plugin Using Eclipse

Tags: plugin-development, eclipse, development-strategy

Anyone who has experience in building wordpress plugin using eclipse PDT?

My situation is:

- I need to build plugin that extend another plugin (look at it as premium version from another plugin)
- I already created project `plugin core`(the original plugin) by importing from svn repository
- I created eclipse library called `wordpress` and added it to `plugin core` project.
- I created another project `plugin extender` which will host scripts I created.

The problem is, how to easily test it to wordpress, without having to manually copy-paste those project to `wp-content/plugins`? Is there anyway to automatically copy those files to `wp-content/plugins`? Or, do you guys have another solutions to this problem?

As a side note, I'm working on windows 7. I'm aware of windows's `mklink`. However, my htdocs in on FAT32 partition and I'm in situation where I have to use Windows in the following months.

Comment: this is really an eclipse question - best addressed over at programmers.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow

Comment: I will let this brew for a bit in case someone has hands-on WP/Eclipse experience with such... If not indeed better to migrate to site that might be more fitting.

Comment: Rarst, my thoughts exactly.

Comment: OK, but I think what the OP wants is a way to use Eclipse to copy files from one folder (his working directory) to another (the plugin folder in his WP install). @silent - doesn't RSE (http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) do what you need?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Create WordPress as a project. I have several such projects, trunk, old versions … for the following, I just use a project named **WP Latest Final**.
   You can use the standard installation with `/wp-content/plugins`. I put my `wp-content` directory in a Dropbox and [tell WP via wp-config.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15483/symbolic-links-on-dev-box-with-plugins-and-stylesheets/15484#15484) where to search for it.
2. Create a new PHP project for each of your plugins. Use **Create project from existing source** and point to the plugin directory in `/wp-content/plugins`.

   [image]
3. Click **Next** in the project wizard, and go to the **Projects** tab. Choose **Add … WP Latest Final**.

   [image]
4. Select **Access Rules** and exclude `wp-admin/load-scripts.php` and `wp-admin/load-styles.php`. [Hat tip](http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Hakre#WordPress_Eclipse_1x1) to [@hakre](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/178/hakre).

   [image]
5. Add more projects as you need, other plugins, theme projects etc.
6. Click **Finish**. Done.

If you have installed [Egit](http://eclipse.org/egit/), you probably want to create a new Git project now to get independent from Eclipse’s history tracking.

Comment: Hmm.. using this strategy means that I have to build the project on wordpress's wp-content/plugins? this'll do. Thanks.

Comment: Not on the whole plugin directory, just the one with your plugin.

Comment: yea, I get that.

Answer (score 0):

### Eclipse » Aptana

Just a short addition for all those using [Aptana](http://aptana.com/).

When you already got a project that is (physically/on disk) outside your WordPress development copy, then simply go to

> Project » Properties » PHP Buildpath » [`♦ External Directories`]

[image]