# How to handle PHP parse errors?

Tags: php, errors, parse

I tried to execute the following code and I got a parsing error message (line:3). Here is the code on Pastebin http://pastebin.com/gC7rsJqw.

I tried echoing but didn't seem to solve the problem. Maybe I missed something. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the PHP context if you use raw HTML output. Instead of …

```
<?php
global $EM_Event;
<div class="content_left">

    <?php gteventstore_before_loop(); ?>
```

… close PHP before the div:

```
<?php
global $EM_Event;
?>
<div class="content_left">

    <?php gteventstore_before_loop(); ?>
```

Use an IDE with a PHP parser to see such syntax errors early. You code looks in [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) like this:

[image]

If you tip the red icon you get an explanation:

[image]

Read more [about Eclipse and WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14473/strategy-on-building-plugin-using-eclipse/14495#14495).