# Create entire wordpress as a github repositery?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, git

In my IDE (Flash Builder for PHP), I can't find a way to create sub project inside Wordpress project as I did with NetBeans. Seems I need to make entire WordPress as a github local repo in order to add version control for my small plugin. Is there other ways I can import git repo as a project inside main project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to make this easier:

1. Set WordPress as a separate project and associate it with your current sub project as shown in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14473/strategy-on-building-plugin-using-eclipse/14495#14495).
2. If 1. isn’t possible manage the Git repository from a terminal and don’t use the limited build-in Git manager in Flash Builder.