# Where is the query in wp-login.php

Tags: query, login

I am making a login form in WordPress and i want to have a validation on it, so i tried to look at the wp-login.php to see how they validate things. But i did not find what i am looking for. I would like to know how they validate things or what input do they need to validate things. I tried to search the WordPress forums all i can find is plugin, plugin and more plugin. I don't want a plugin. I want to hard code it. So please help me.

I want to know where you can find the part that searches for the user's username and password.
Or if not, know what is needed for a successful login. example username or password or others.
by the way here is the [wp-login.php](http://pastebin.com/Kn416sxw). Thanks

Comment: Just to let you know, no one here will tell you how to hardcode it into WordPress Core.  Hacking core is a [***bad idea***](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files). Any code we give you will be in the form of a plugin.

Comment: When you say hard code it, do you mean within your theme?

Comment: Yes, my theme. any ideas??

Comment: Just to clear up some confusion - it does not appear that he is trying to edit a core file. Rather you can have a wp-login.php file in your theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `wp-includes/general-template.php` at the function `wp_login_form()`. Follow the functions called there. I’d say: just *use* `wp_login_form()`. It does probably everything you need, and you can customize it.

Comment: i had a hard time locating these files, do you know a site or a linke that has a directory mapping of these files. nice tip though

Comment: I use Eclipse and the [WordPress core as a separate project](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14473/strategy-on-building-plugin-using-eclipse/14495#14495). Then I just through this project.

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit `wp-login.php` file. Instead create a new page for your login. If you don't have any coding knowledge use readymade plugins. 
There are many plugins available to create frontend login form.

For example check this [Profile builder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/profile-builder/screenshots/) plugin.

Also check [Theme my login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin

Answer (score 1):

I would use this in your situation:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/

Yes - it's a plugin: You then just drop wp-login.php as a page template in your theme.

Note - try it without the plugin - it may not even be needed at this point.

---

Here are some tutorials that do it without a plugin:

http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/custom-wordpress-login-screen/

http://wplift.com/how-to-create-a-custom-login-page-for-your-wordpress-theme