# Where to find the source code of a widget?

Tags: widgets

i would like to find the source code of the *widgets*, would you know where to find them? I found the class WP_Widget, but i would like to find, for example, the widget with the last articles.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default widgets are defined in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`.

To find specific code search the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) or use [queryposts.com](http://queryposts.com/). The best tool is your IDE (integrated development environment). All IDEs offer a full text search in a set of files.

Here a screen shot from [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt)

[image]

As you can see it is really flexible – and it's fast too. See also [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14495/73) for a basic guide on how to work with WordPress in an IDE.

Comment: another link to find the source code of WordPress functions: http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?_functions/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Widgets can come from any number of sources: plugins, themes, or the core itself. As such, finding the code for a specific widget could prove troublesome if you do not know it's origin. You could grep for it using bits you know, or grep for all widgets using `extends WP_Widget`. If you know where it comes from (core, plugin, etc) it's a simple matter of thumbing (or greping, I suppose) through code.