# Where can you find the available filter tags?

Tags: filters, tags

In my attempt to alter navigations current-menu-item class, I found a possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/7941864/520265 ,

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
```

He makes use of a filter who is called with a tag 'nav_menu_css_class' , But it got me wondering, where can you find information about what filters are available to use?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu does not mention anything about filters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple was to find filters:

1. Use an IDE (see [Eclipse example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14495/73)), set WordPress as a separate project and search in this project for `apply_filters` or `do_action`.
2. Get a program to search in all files of a directory (grep, Notepad++) and do the same search with that.
3. Read the source code. If you start with `wp_nav_menu()` and follow the functions called in its definition you will find the filters and actions you need.

Comment: Great, source code it is , thanks! (will accept in couple of minutes)

Comment: Try [grin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grin), it's the best way to read source code IMHO :) (if on Linux, just install it from your package manager)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the available filters are listed in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)

[Adam Brown](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks) hosts a much more complete list of action and filter hooks.

You can also search through the source, as @toscho [mentioned](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76247/19726).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the plugin [Debug Objects](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects); the plugin list action and filter hooks on the current page or all hooks.