# How to create a flexible abstraction for WP_Query?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, oop

My question is about php but it involves wordpress as i am creating a plugin. The case is that i have 5 questions, each question have 6 choices and one choice to choose from each. Now the person would select any choice from each or just few. I have created the if condition that is now making me mad, as it has gone too long and will do further, like nearly 100 combination will be made. I wouldn't want that, i know there is a way of multidimensional array but in am not a plugin or php expert for wordpress. so if anyone can sort it for me.

```
$qs = $_POST['q1'];
$q2 = $_POST['q2'];
$q3 = $_POST['q3'];
$q4 = $_POST['q4'];
$q5 = $_POST['q5'];
$q6 = $_POST['q6'];



 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'fashion-follower'
    ),
//    array(
//     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
//     'field' => 'slug',
//     'terms' => 'cheap-and-cheerful'
//    )
  )
);
 //The Fashionsia
 if (($qs ==='party') && ($q2 === 'clothes') && ($q3 === 'shopping') && ($q5 === 'Sunbathing') && ($q6 === 'mini')){

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

     the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');

endwhile;
    endif;      
}

//second question loop

$args2 = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'the-homemaker'
    ),
//    array(
//     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
//     'field' => 'slug',
//     'terms' => 'cheap-and-cheerful'
//    )
  )
);
 //The homemaker
 if (($qs ==='drink') && ($q2 === 'candles') && ($q3 === 'house') && ($q4 === 'diy')){

$query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
if( $query->have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

     the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');

endwhile;
    endif;      
}
//third loop

$args3 = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'entertainment'
    ),
//    array(
//     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
//     'field' => 'slug',
//     'terms' => 'cheap-and-cheerful'
//    )
  )
);
 //The Entertainer
 if (($qs ==='party-babe') && ($q2 === 'winer')&& ($q4 === 'storm') && ($q6 === 'limo')){

$query = new WP_Query( $args3 );
if( $query->have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

     the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');

endwhile;
    endif;      
}
//fourth loop
$args4 = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'family-fanatic'
    ),
//    array(
//     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
//     'field' => 'slug',
//     'terms' => 'cheap-and-cheerful'
//    )
  )
);
 //The family-fanatic
 if (($qs ==='movie') && ($q2 === 'kids')&& ($q6 === 'volvo')){

$query = new WP_Query( $args4 );
if( $query->have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

     the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');

endwhile;
    endif;      
}
//fifth loop
//fourth loop
$args4 = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'family-fanatic'
    ),
//    array(
//     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
//     'field' => 'slug',
//     'terms' => 'cheap-and-cheerful'
//    )
  )
);
 //The romantic
 if (($qs ==='Dinner-show') && ($q5 === 'cruiser')){

$query = new WP_Query( $args4 );
if( $query->have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

     the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');

endwhile;
    endif;      
}
```

Comment: What is the difference to [your earlier question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111705/refactoring-loop-to-make-it-small-and-smart)?

Comment: @toscho the difference is that in that Q. there was question about refactoring but now i am asking on optimizing the code along with wp the loop or having it done in array.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question is not really about WordPress, it is more about PHP and refactoring. But we see so much bad code here, and the pattern I will explain below (MVC) could help many other developers, so I decided to write a little answer. Keep in mind, there is a dedicated site for such questions in our network: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Unfortunately, very few WordPress developers are active there.

---

### How to refactor code

1. Remove useless code. Beautify the rest.
2. Find all repeating expressions and create routines (functions or classes) to
   abstract and encapsulate those.
3. Separate data handling, the **model** (store, fetch, conversion, interpretation),
   from output, the **view** (HTML, CSV, whatever).

### 1. Remove useless code. Beautify the rest.

#### The output

You have this repeating snippet:

```
if( $query->have_posts()) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');

endwhile;
endif;
```

You run the rather expensive `the_post()` each time to get the post thumbnail.
But that’s not needed, you can just call:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'post-thumbnail' );
```

#### The query

So all you need is the post ID, and this is available without calling `the_post()`.
Even better: you can restrict the query to fetch *just* the IDs.

A simple example:

```
$post_ids = array();
$args     = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'fields'         => 'ids'
);
$query    = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( ! empty ( $query->posts ) )
    $post_ids = $query->posts; // just the post IDs
```

Now you have the IDs, and you can write:

```
foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id )
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'post-thumbnail' );
```

No overhead, your code is already faster and easier to read.

#### The syntax

Note how I aligned the `=`? This helps understanding the code, because the human
mind is specialized in pattern recognition. Support that and we can do awesome
things. Create a mess, and we get stuck very fast.

This is also the reason why I removed `endwhile` and `endif`. The [alternative
syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) is messy and hard to read. Plus, it makes [working in an IDE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/83223/73) much harder:
folding and jumping from the start to the end of an expression is easier with
braces.

#### The default values

Your `$args` array has some fields you use everywhere. Create a default array,
and write those fields just *once*:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
        )
    )
);
```

Again, note the alignment. And note also how I changed the `posts_per_page` value.
**Never ask for `-1`**. What happens when there are one million matching posts?
You don’t want to kill your database connection each time this query runs, do you?
And who should read all these posts? Always set a reasonable limit.

Now all you have to change is the field `$args[ 'tax_query' ][ 'terms' ]`. We will cover that in a moment.

### 2. Find all repeating expressions and create routines

We cleaned up some repeating code already, now the hard part: the evaluation of
POST parameters. Obviously, you have made some labels as a result of some
parameters. I suggest to rename those to something easier to understand, but for
now we will work with your naming scheme.

Separate these groups from the rest, create an array you can manage later separately:

```
$groups = array(
    'fashion-follower' => array(
        'q1' => 'party',
        'q2' => 'clothes',
        'q3' => 'shopping',
        'q4' => FALSE,
        'q5' => 'sunbathing',
        'q6' => 'mini',
    ),
    'the-homemaker' => array(
        'q1' => 'drink',
        'q2' => 'candles',
        'q3' => 'house',
        'q4' => 'diy',
        'q5' => FALSE,
        'q6' => FALSE,
    )
);
```

To fill the missing `terms` field in your default array, you run through the
`$groups` array until you find a match:

```
function get_query_term( $groups )
{
    foreach ( $groups as $term => $values )
    {
        if ( compare_group_values( $values ) )
            return $term;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

function compare_group_values( $values )
{
    foreach ( $values as $key => $value )
    {
        // Key not sent, but required
        if ( empty ( $_POST[ $key ] ) and ! empty ( $value ) )
            return FALSE;

        // Key sent, but wrong value
        if ( ! empty ( $_POST[ $key ] ) and $_POST[ $key ] !== $value )
            return FALSE;
    }

    // all keys matched the required values
    return TRUE;
}
```

I separated even the run through the term list and the comparison of the values,
because these are different operations. Every part of your code should do just
one thing, and you have to keep the indentation level flat for better readability.

Now we have all the parts, let’s stick them together.

### 3. Organization: Separate the model from the view

When I wrote *model* and *view*, I had something in mind: the MVC approach.
It stands for *[Model View Controller](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html)*, a well known pattern to organize software
components. The missing part so far was the controller, we will see how we use it later.

You said, you don’t know much about PHP, so I hope you know more about the output. :)
Let’s start with that:

```
class Thumbnail_List
{
    protected $source;

    public function set_source( Post_Collector_Interface $source )
    {
        $this->source = $source;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $post_ids = $this->source->get_post_ids();

        if ( empty ( $post_ids ) or ! is_array( $post_ids ) )
            return print 'Nothing found';

        foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id )
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'post-thumbnail' );
    }
}
```

Nice and simple: we have two methods: one to set the source for our post IDs,
one to render the thumbnails.

You might wonder what this `Post_Collector_Interface` is. We get to that in a moment.

Now the source for our view, the model.

```
class Post_Collector implements Post_Collector_Interface
{
    protected $groups = array();

    public function set_groups( Array $groups )
    {
        $this->groups = $groups;
    }

    public function get_post_ids()
    {
        $term = $this->get_query_term();

        if ( ! $term )
            return array();

        return $this->query( $term );
    }

    protected function query( $term )
    {
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 100,
            'fields'         => 'ids',
            'tax_query'      => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $term
                )
            )
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( empty ( $query->posts ) )
            return array();

        return $query->posts;
    }

    protected function get_query_term()
    {
        foreach ( $this->groups as $term => $values )
        {
            if ( compare_group_values( $values ) )
                return $term;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    protected function compare_group_values( $values )
    {
        foreach ( $values as $key => $value )
        {
            // Key not sent, but required
            if ( empty ( $_POST[ $key ] ) and ! empty ( $value ) )
                return FALSE;

            // Kent sent, but wrong value
            if ( ! empty ( $_POST[ $key ] ) and $_POST[ $key ] !== $value )
                return FALSE;
        }

        // all keys matched the required values
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

This is not so trivial anymore, but we had the most parts already. The `protected` methods (functions) are not accessible from the outside, because we need them for the internal logic only.

The `public` methods are simple: the first gets our `$group` array from above,
the second returns an array of post IDs. And again we meet this dubious `Post_Collector_Interface`.

An interface is a contract. It can be signed (implemented) by classes. Requiring
an interface, like our class `Thumbnail_List` does, means: the class expects *some* other class with these public methods.

Let’s build that interface. It is really simple:

```
interface Post_Collector_Interface
{
    public function set_groups( Array $groups );

    public function get_post_ids();
}
```

Yup, that’s all. Easy code, isn’t it?

What we did here: we made our view `Thumbnail_List` independent from a concrete
class while we still can *rely* on the methods of the class we got as `$source`.
If you change your mind later, you can write a new class to fetch the post IDs
or use one with fixed values. As long as you implement the interface, the view
will be satisfied. You can even test the view now with a mock object:

```
class Mock_Post_Collector implements Post_Collector_Interface
{
    public function set_groups( Array $groups ) {}

    public function get_post_ids()
    {
        return array ( 1 );
    }
}
```

This is very useful when you want to **test** the view. You don’t want to test both
concrete classes together, because the you wouldn’t see where an error comes from.
The mock object is too simple for errors, ideal for unit tests.

Now we have to combine our classes somehow. This is where the controller enters
the stage.

```
class Thumbnail_Controller
{
    protected $groups = array(
        'fashion-follower' => array(
            'q1' => 'party',
            'q2' => 'clothes',
            'q3' => 'shopping',
            'q4' => FALSE,
            'q5' => 'sunbathing',
            'q6' => 'mini',
        ),
        'the-homemaker' => array(
            'q1' => 'drink',
            'q2' => 'candles',
            'q3' => 'house',
            'q4' => 'diy',
            'q5' => FALSE,
            'q6' => FALSE,
        )
    );
    public function __construct()
    {
        // not a post request
        if ( 'POST' !== $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] )
            return;

        // set up the model
        $model = new Post_Collector;
        $model->set_groups( $this->groups );

        // prepare the view
        $view = new Thumbnail_List;
        $view->set_source( $model );

        // finally render the tumbnails
        $view->render();
    }
}
```

The controller is the one real unique part of an application; the model and the view might be re-used here and there, even in completely different parts. But the controller exists for just this single purpose, this is why we put the `$group` here.

And now you have to do just one thing:

```
// Let the dogs out!
new Thumbnail_Controller;
```

Call this line wherever you need the output.

You can find all the code from this answer in this [gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/thefuxia/6385459).

Comment: What's the ISBN number of that answer?

Comment: Textbook answer indeed :p

Comment: "Never ask for -1." I would say: put a filter on `-1` so users with huge sites can change it if they need to.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy I’d rather set safe defaults and let users who need `-1` add that per filter. Which is already possible with a filter on the query.