# Best way to use variables in multiple functions?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, variables

So I am running into issues in Query Monitor - duplicate queries. The reason being that I have functions that need to get say, a customer's order status or the like.

What is the cleanest, correct way to ensure I only make that query once, but can use the results of that query in another function?

Sorry, I know its a very noob question, I just want to start cleaning up code and do things properly.

Comment: Create a class for your functions and then use a class function to set a class variable that can be called in other  functions.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if we could see your actual code. See also [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112196/73) for example.

Comment: @fuxia - this gist listed at the bottom of that great answer is 404.

Comment: @shanebp Thanks, fixed.