# cannot echo the_post_thumbnails

Tags: theme-development

I'm using the following PHP code to echo post thumbnails.

```
  <?php
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post' ,
  'orderby' => 'date' ,
  'order' => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'category'         => '2',
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
  'post_parent' => $parent
  );
  // The Query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  // The Loop
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
          echo '' . the_post_thumbnail() . '';
      }
  } else {
      // no posts found
  }
  /* Restore original Post Data */
  wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
```

But I'm having issue, since this wont work, but when I try to echo `get_post_title()` it works perfectly fine.
I can't figure out where do I got this wrong.

How can I display/echo post thumbnails?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but the problem you're having with this specific bit of code is that you're using the wrong function. You want **get_the_post_thumbnail()** instead. The function the_post_thumbnail() echoes the result of get_the_post_thumbnail().

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'category' => '2',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'post_parent' => $parent
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
    }
} else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, not sure why, I guess I'm uploading the image wrong to the post maybe.

Comment: The image has to be set as the Featured Image in order for this to work. If you don't want to use featured image, you'll have to jump through some hoops to get the attached images and output the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
'posts_per_page' => 1,
```

Do you really only want a single post to be returned?
And what is the `$parent` value?

Since you don't want anything but the post thumbnail, specify that you only need the post id(s).
Try:

```
  $args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'post' ,
  'orderby'        => 'date' ,
  'order'          => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'category'       => '2',
  'paged'          => get_query_var('paged'),
  'post_parent'    => $parent,
  'fields'         => 'ids'
  );
  // The Query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( ! empty ( $query->posts ) ) {

      $post_ids = $query->posts; // just the post IDs

      foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id )
          echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'post-thumbnail' );

  } else {
      echo 'No posts were found';
  }
  /* Restore original Post Data */
  wp_reset_postdata();
```

A good and relevant read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112184/how-to-create-a-flexible-abstraction-for-wp-query/112196#112196).

Comment: Somehow it returns "no posts were found", even though I've uploaded image to the post.

Comment: Remove the `category` and `post_parent` and `paged` and `posts_per_page` fields and test again.  Then add in those fields, one at a  time, and test until you find the issue.

Comment: I've removed all you said, nothing seems to work. maybe I'm uploading the image wrong to the post? I mean when I adding new post, I click on the + sign on the top and upload image.

Comment: Did you set the Featured Image in the right column?

Comment: Solved it by printing the entire post directly with post id.